# Install QGIS on Ubuntu using the compressed format qgis-2.8.3.tar.bz2

Tags: qgis, python, installation, ubuntu

I just can't use `apt install` because slow internet connection here in Africa moreover the size of QGIS is huge.

Thus, I am using other ways to install and configure.

I have tried decompressing and run `./configure` which resulted in an error.

Is there a way to use the decompressed file to install QGIS?

Comment: You can download the deb packages directly from http://qgis.org/ubuntugis/pool/main/q/qgis/ , resuming with wget or whatever tool you used for the tarball should work. I would recommend that instead of compiling yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The tarball (.tar.bz2) file which you have downloaded contains the source code for QGIS. So in order to *install* it you have to *build* it first.

QGIS does not come with a configure file but instead uses the cmake build system.

In short you will do

```
cd qgis-2.8.3
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
make
```

The full installation build and instructions can be found here:

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/doc/INSTALL.html

**Warning**
Be aware that QGIS requires a number of dependencies which need to be installed before building, so they may also be too much for your internet connection to handle.

Comment: this actually compilation that need additional package to be installed right,anyway I have installed it as follow

Comment: This might have worked at other linux versions, but did not work for Ubuntu 18.04 and qgis 3.4

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Since internet coneection was slower in my case I used axel download accelleretot to do the apt-install like the way on this [link](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-apt-fast-download-accelerator-in-ubuntu-12-0411-1010-04)

so apt-get replaced with apt-fast

to install package name use

sudo apt-fast install